# Unwarranted Redirect(s) with Nginx Sites

Tags: nginx

My Nginx sites are currently a little bit wonky.

I have a reverse proxy to my public-facing hastebin instance that works fine. However I am trying to setup Outline, but it's redirecting to my Webmin instance. You can see via the following links:

[Outline](https://docs.greemdev.net)
docs.greemdev.net is showing the content of admin.greemdev.net when it shouldn't be. Webmin is on port 10000 and Outline is on 3000.

[Hastebin](https://paste.greemdev.net)
I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Link to my Nginx configuration for docs.greemdev.net and paste.greemdev.net:

[nginx](https://paste.greemdev.net/eweluvihehotaxivowaxowicosukof.nginx)
[hastebin](https://paste.greemdev.net/ujufovotokasisevimulatuxilufif.nginx)

If I need to provide any more of my configurations let me know.

Comment: Try removing the `localhost` restriction from the `listen` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith I had omitted that previously, same issue. I just had that in because I thought it'd work. Nope.

Answer (score 0):

"Solved"

I switched to [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com).

Caddy offers automatic Let's Encrypt SSL encryption, as well as a less convoluted configuration file syntax. I switched over because Nginx was doing this to my other sites as well, and it was annoying me.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  This would be more helpful to other readers with a similar problem if you could add a few sentences to explain how you decided on that solution, and why that's a good solution for you.

Comment: @fixer1234 Will do.

Comment: It sounds like Nginx was acting flaky, so you tried Caddy, and it doesn't exhibit the same problems?  So maybe not that there's a specific feature you can point to that explains why Caddy works better, you just tried it and discovered that it does?